# indent-issues in a tiny python script :: fixed the code - now it runs like perfect

Tags: python, linux

have had some ident-issues with a tiny python-script
**update:** see the new issues  that have arised after i have had rewritten the class...:

**update:**  - finally  got there

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
"""
contacts.py
This program uses a Person class to keep track of contacts.
"""
class Person(object):
    """
    The Person class defines a person in terms of a
    name, phone number, and email address.
    """

    # Constructor
    def __init__(self, name, phone, email, padress):
        self.name = name
        self.phone = phone
        self.email = email
        self.padress = padress

    def __str__(self):
        return "Person[name={}, phone={}, email={}, padress={}]".format(self.name, self.phone,
                                                                       self.email, self.padress)
# create instance person = Person(name='John Doe', phone='123454321', email='john.doe@domain.com', adress='1600 Pennsylvania ave., Washington DC')
# access property
    # Accesser Methods (getters)
    def getName(self):
        return self.name
    def getPhone(self):
        return self.phone
    def getEmail(self):
        return self.email
    def getpadress(self):
        return self.padress

 # Mutator Methods (setters)
    def setPhone(self, newPhoneNumber):
        self.phone = newPhoneNumber
    def setEmail(self, newEmailAddress):
        self.email = newEmailAddress
    def setPadress(self, newPadress):
        self.padress = newPadress
    def __str__(self):
        return "Person[name=" + self.name + \
               ",phone=" + self.phone + \
               ",email=" + self.email + \
               ",padress=" + self.padress + \
               "]"

def enter_a_friend():
    name = input("Enter friend's name: ")
    phone = input("Enter phone number: ")
    email = input("Enter email address: ")
    padress = input("Enter friend's padress:")
    return Person(name, phone, email, padress)

def lookup_a_friend(friends):
    found = False
    name = input("Enter name to lookup: ")
    for friend in friends:
        if name in friend.getName():
            print(friend)
            found = True
    if not found:
        print("No friends match that term")

def show_all_friends(friends):
    print("Showing all contacts:")
    for friend in friends:
        print(friend)

def main():
    friends = []
    running = True
    while running:
        print("\nContacts Manager")
        print("1) new contact    2) lookup")
        print("3) show all       4) end ")
        option = input("> ")
        if option == "1":
            friends.append(enter_a_friend())
        elif option == "2":
            lookup_a_friend(friends)
        elif option == "3":
            show_all_friends(friends)
        elif option == "4":
            running = False
        else:
            print("Unrecognized input. Please try again.")
    print("Program ending.")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

fixed the code now it runs perfect!! 
next time i try to add a db connection to this code - i will try to do this with peewee. 
Peewee is a simple and small ORM. It has few (but expressive) concepts, making it easy to learn and intuitive to use.

```
a small, expressive ORM
python 2.7+ and 3.4+ (developed with 3.6)
supports sqlite, mysql and postgresql
tons of extensions
```

> Peewee will automatically infer the database table name from the name
>   of the class. You can override the default name by specifying a
>   table_name attribute in the inner “Meta” class (alongside the database
>   attribute). To learn more about how Peewee generates table names,
>   refer to the Table Names section.

guess i will give it a try

Comment: The error message is clear: line 63 (in main(), `running = True`) is indented, but it should not be

Comment: Hello dear Maton - many thanks: i switch off the indent - so that is is not indented

Comment: hello dear Martin - update: have some ident-issues with a tiny python-script update: see the new issues that have arised after i have had rewritten the class..

Comment: dar martin - i have added some new /(rewritten) class - but run into more issues now... - unfortunatly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### The error

The `print` functions halfway through your class are closing the class declaration, making the rest of the indented things after them not count as part of the class. You need to move your accessor methods to before the `print` functions as you are making an instance of the class in the middle of its definition.

#### Code fixes

It's also very bad practice to put statements at a base level in your file (not in a function) and then being followed up by a `main()` function and `if __name__ == "__main__":`

You should move these print statements into your `main()` function to get them out of global space, which will also fix your indentation errors in the process.

Your accessors can be simplified using some of python's syntax as well. Python doesn't have private variables (similar to Java) where the complier will prohibit you from actually referencing these values. Therefore, you really don't need to use accessors. It prevents unnecessary code that would be used normally just for setting a value and it gives you cleaner syntax, as you're just setting a value to the property instead of in a function. If you really want to have private variables, the standard is to just prepend the variable name with an underscore.